# Ajax Form loaded in a DIV using Ajax request redirects on submit - Framework7

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 to load an Ajax page as follows in myapp.js:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
rules: {
aiterms: {
required: true
    }
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
$$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var myterms;
var mybookingid;
$("#submit").unbind().click(function() {
myterms = $("#myterms").val();
mybookingid = $("#my_booking_id").val();
if ($('#myterms').is(":checked")==false)
{
myApp.alert('You need to accept terms to proceed further!', 'Terms Not Accepted!'); 
    }
else
{
$$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "submit1.php",
dataType : 'html',
data: {myterms1: myterms,mybookingid1: mybookingid },
cache: false,
success: function(result){
$("#mycontent" ).empty();
$("#mycontent").html(result);
},//success
error: function(result) 
     {   
myApp.alert('We are unable to process data due to technical reasons!', 'Error');
      }  
   });
}//else
return false;
     });
   }//submit handler
}); //validate
```

and a form from my_submit1 page gets updated in `#mycontent` div:

```
<div  id="mycontent" >
```

the form in second page submits as

```
<form id="form2">
....
<input type="submit" name="submit"  id="mysubmit1" value="Submit" />
```

and in myapp.js:

```
$$(document).on('click','#mysubmit1',function(){
var a = $("#a").val();
var b = $("#b").val();
var c = $("input[name='c']:checked").val(); //radio button
.....

if(a == '')
{
myApp.alert('Please select and enter data a!', 'Insufficient Data');
  }
else if(b =='')
{
myApp.alert('Please select and enter data b!', 'Insufficient Data');
   }
else if ($('.c').is(":checked")==false)
{
myApp.alert('Please select whether c selected or not!', 'Insufficient Data');
   }
...
else
{
$$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "submit2.php",
dataType : 'html',
data: {a: a,b: b,c: c},
cache: false,
success: function(result){
$("#mycontent" ).empty();
$("#mycontent").html(result);
},//success
error: function(result) 
{   
myApp.alert('We are unable to process data due to technical reasons!', 'Error');
       }  
    });
  }//else
return false;
```

});

The second form loaded on submit **the alert is displayed  momentarily and the page is getting redirected**. Moreover variables **are passed as GET instead of POST** as specified in the Ajax request.

The first form submit is updating the div correctly. Issue happens only with second form (replaced form data in div).
I am unable to detect the reason. Is something wrong with way i pass the second request ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update  in myapp.js:

Change From

```
$$(document).on('click','#mysubmit1',function(){
```

To

```
$$(document).on('click','#mysubmit1',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: wow Dear! Thank you so much!. I missed it completely. New to javascript. :)